# iOS: Recieveing a crash NSInvalidArgumentException NSConcreteMutableAttributedString addAttribute:value:range:: nil value

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, string

This is the line that the error is occurring on.

```
 [self addAttribute:(__bridge NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(__bridge id)color.CGColor range:range];
```

This is the full method code.

```
 -(void)setTextColor:(UIColor*)color range:(NSRange)range
 {
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
// kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
[self removeAttribute:(__bridge NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName range:range]; // Work around for Apple leak
[self addAttribute:(__bridge NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(__bridge id)color.CGColor range:range];
   }}
```

I tried testing if range is not found, but the error still occured. Any tips or suggestions on what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because `(__bridge id)color.CGColor` is `nil`.
Just do like this, without any extra conversions

```
[self addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:range];
```

Answer (score 0):

it wrong checking in yours case, you need:

```
if (range.location >= 0 && range.location < self.length){
    if (range.location + range.length >= self.length)
        range.length = self.length - range.location;

    [self removeAttribute:(__bridge NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName range:range]; // Work around for Apple leak
    [self addAttribute:(__bridge NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(__bridge id)color.CGColor range:range];
}
```